# Какая библиотека Python для telegram имеет методы для парсинга

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Какая библиотека Python для telegram имеет методы для парсинга постов с каналов подписавшегося на бота юзера в другой один канал ? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: То есть вы хотите, чтобы бот отследил, кто на него подписался, посмотрел в личные подписки этого человека, нашел там какие-то другие каналы и начал с них брать посты и пересылать в другой канал?

Comment: @Redirectsbot 2.0 идеальный бот Хочется научиться написать подобный! он позволяет выбрать каналы из своих подписок и чтоб бот из этих каналов свежие посты в один канал постил для юзера

Comment: Python-Telegram-Bot или telebot

Comment: Благодарю за наводку! Погружаюсь